# Using Dell's WWAN 5520 GPS

Tags: dell, 12.04, gps

I have a Dell D430 laptop, with Dell's WWAN 5520 chip in miniPCIe port on Ubuntu 12.04

The 3G part of it works fine, but when it comes to using the GPS module, I'm clueless how to even begin.

I installed viking, with its dependencies, but I don't know if I need to load some module for the GPS part, whats the interface that I should use with viking, and pretty much anything else that I should know.

I think the card is actually a USB module, bridged via PCIe, it's also based on Novatel EU870D chip.

lsusb returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:8137 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 5520 Voda L Mobile Broadband (3G HSDPA) Minicard Status Port
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!